# Present simple vs. present continuous

Tags: grammar, tense, present-tense, present-continuous, present-simple

Why is there present simple in the first sentence? Why is there no present continuous?

> **I scowl** with frustration at myself in the mirror. Damn my hair – it just won’t behave,
> and damn Katherine Kavanagh for being ill and subjecting me to this ordeal. I should be
> studying for my final exams, which are next week, yet here I am trying to brush my hair
> into submission.

Comment: This is probably an excerpt from a story. In literature, style is very important and that is probably the reason the present simple is used in the first part of the sentence. More a matter of style than grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Present continuous often combines with verb which express repeating action,but the verb "scowl" here is not to describe a repeating action.